# How to highlight specific word of the text in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I wanted to know how to highlight the specific part of the text in jetpack compose. I tried `Html.fromHtml()` like this

```
Text(text = Html.fromHtml(" <font color='red'> Hello </font> World").toString())
```

But it didn't work. Is there any way I can do this in compose?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [**`AnnotatedString`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString) to display the text with multiple styles.

Something like:

```
Text(buildAnnotatedString {
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Red)) {
        append("Hello")
    }
    append(" World ")
})
```

[image]

Comment: What if I already have a string and I want to highlight from a specific index to another specific index?

Comment: @BugsHappen Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73835998/13806019

Answer (score 5):

You can use [AnnotatedString](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString) to append each word/section with it's own style or to add different style at any index which is great if you're using a string resource.

For the hello world example you could construct something like this:

```kotlin
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    val str = "Hello World" // or stringResource(id = R.string.hello_world)
    val boldStr = "Hello" // or stringResource(id = R.string.hello)
    val startIndex = str.indexOf(boldStr)
    val endIndex = startIndex + boldStr.length
    append(str)
    addStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Red), start = startIndex, end = endIndex)
}
Text(
    text = annotatedString,
)
```

[image: Hello world text with the letters of hello in red]

Using `addStyle` in this way allows us to do some fun things like adding multiple styles to the same text

```kotlin
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    val str = "Hello Wonderful World" // or stringResource(id = R.string.hello_world)
    val boldStr = "Wonderful World" // or stringResource(id = R.string.world)
    val startIndex = str.indexOf(boldStr)
    val endIndex = startIndex + boldStr.length
    append(str)
    addStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Red), start = startIndex, end = endIndex)

    val italicsStr = "Wonderful"
    val italicsStartIndex = str.indexOf(italicsStr)
    val italicsEndIndex = startIndex + italicsStr.length
    addStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic), start = italicsStartIndex, end = italicsEndIndex)
}
Text(
    text = annotatedString,
    style = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
    color = Color.Blue,
)
```

[image: The text hello wonderful world with varied color and italics]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `addStyle()` - I was already down a rabbit hole of splitting and reassembling the string. When highlighting auto-complete options with this method, it's a good idea to also check `if (startIndex > -1)` before calling it.

Answer (score 3):

Check this function below. Here paragraph is your string  source and searchQuery is the specific text you want to highlight.

This provides you a dynamic state for text and search highlights.

```
@Composable
    fun getData(): StateFlow<AnnotatedString?> {

        val span = SpanStyle(
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            background = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer
        )

        return combine(paragraph, searchQuery) { text, query ->
            buildAnnotatedString {
                var start = 0
                while (text.indexOf(query, start, ignoreCase = true) != -1 && query.isNotBlank()) {
                    val firstIndex = text.indexOf(query, start, true)
                    val end = firstIndex + query.length
                    append(text.substring(start, firstIndex))
                    withStyle(style = span) {
                        append(text.substring(firstIndex, end))
                    }
                    start = end
                }
                append(text.substring(start, text.length))
                toAnnotatedString()
            }
        }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), null)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from Matt Smith's answer but in a more reusable and flexible way with taking a list of `Pair` precising the `placeholder` and a `SpanStyle` (instead of a `Pair` it can be a custom `data class` if you need anything else...)

Then iterate over the `list` to annotate the `string` with the corresponding `SpanStyle` to their `placeholder`.

```
@Composable
fun annotateRecursively(
    placeHolderList: List<Pair<String, SpanStyle>>,
    originalText: String
): AnnotatedString {
    var annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString { append(originalText) }
    for (item in placeHolderList) {
        annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
            val startIndex = annotatedString.indexOf(item.first)
            val endIndex = startIndex + item.first.length
            append(annotatedString)
            addStyle(style = item.second, start = startIndex, end = endIndex)
        }
    }
    return annotatedString
}
```